# Button click event closes Activity insted of running ASyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a wierd problem with my application. On button click I want to run ASyncTask but insted of running task, my current Activity gets closed. I don't know why and I am not sure how to fix it. Does someone knows where is the problem?

```
public class SpeedTestActivity extends BaseActivity {

    private View mRunningBar;
    private TextView uploadLabel;
    private TextView uploading;
    private TextView downloadLabel;
    private TextView downloading;

    private Activity context;
    private SpeedTestSocket speedTestSocket;
    private static final String TAG = "SpeedTesting";
    private long testingTime = 0;
    LineChart chart;
    LineData data;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_speed_test);
        SpeedTestSocket speedTestSocket;
        String TAG = "SpeedTesting";

        downloadLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.downloadingLabel);
        downloading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.downloading);
        uploadLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.uploadingLabel);
        uploading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.uploading);
        mRunningBar = findViewById(R.id.runningBar);
        mRunningBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.start_test).setOnClickListener(testButtonClicked);

        chart = (LineChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);
        ArrayList<Entry> dataset1 = new ArrayList<Entry>();

        ArrayList<Entry> dataset2 = new ArrayList<Entry>();


        ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();
        xVals.add("0");
        xVals.add("1");
        xVals.add("2");
        xVals.add("3");
        xVals.add("4");
        xVals.add("5");
        xVals.add("6");
        xVals.add("7");
        xVals.add("8");
        xVals.add("9");
        xVals.add("10");


        LineDataSet setData1 = new LineDataSet(dataset1, "Download");
        LineDataSet setData2 = new LineDataSet(dataset2, "Upload");
        ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<ILineDataSet>();
        dataSets.add(setData1);
        dataSets.add(setData2);
        data = new LineData(xVals, dataSets);
        chart.setData(data);
        chart.invalidate(); // refresh



        //new SpeedTest(this, mRunningBar, downloadLabel,  uploadLabel, downloading , uploading , chart, data).execute();

    }
    private final View.OnClickListener testButtonClicked = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            new SpeedTestTask().execute();
        }
    };


// scheduling the task at interval

    public class SpeedTestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Float> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            mRunningBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        @Override
        protected Float doInBackground(Void... params) {


            speedTestSocket = new SpeedTestSocket();


          /*  speedTestSocket.startUpload("1.testdebit.info",
                    80, "/", 10000000); //will block until upload is finished*/
            Timer timer = new Timer();

            TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    if (speedTestSocket.getSpeedTestMode() == SpeedTestMode.UPLOAD) {

                        SpeedTestReport uploadReport = speedTestSocket.getLiveUploadReport();
                        Log.i(TAG, "---------------current upload report--------------------");
                        Log.i(TAG, "progress             : " + uploadReport.getProgressPercent() + "%");
                        Log.i(TAG, "transfer rate bit    : " + uploadReport.getTransferRateBit() + "b/s");
                        Log.i(TAG, "transfer rate octet  : " + uploadReport.getTransferRateOctet()*8/1024/1024 + "Mbps");
                        Log.i(TAG, "uploaded for now     : " + uploadReport.getTemporaryPacketSize()
                                + "/" + uploadReport.getTotalPacketSize());
                        testingTime = (uploadReport.getReportTime() - uploadReport.getStartTime()) / 1000;
                        Log.i(TAG, "amount of time       : " + testingTime + "s");

                        data.addEntry(new Entry( (uploadReport.getTransferRateOctet()*8/1024/1024) + 50f, 0), Math.round(testingTime));
                        if (testingTime>=10){
                            speedTestSocket.closeSocketJoinRead();
                        }
                        Log.i(TAG, "--------------------------------------------------------");

                    } else if (speedTestSocket.getSpeedTestMode() == SpeedTestMode.DOWNLOAD) {

                        SpeedTestReport downloadReport = speedTestSocket.getLiveDownloadReport();
                        Log.i(TAG, "---------------current download report--------------------");
                        Log.i(TAG, "progress             : " + downloadReport.getProgressPercent() + "%");
                        Log.i(TAG, "transfer rate bit    : " + downloadReport.getTransferRateBit() + "b/s");
                        Log.i(TAG, "transfer rate octet  : " + downloadReport.getTransferRateOctet()*8/1024/1024 + "Mbps");
                        Log.i(TAG, "downloaded for now   : " + downloadReport.getTemporaryPacketSize()
                                + "/" + downloadReport.getTotalPacketSize());
                        testingTime = (downloadReport.getReportTime() - downloadReport.getStartTime()) / 1000;
                        Log.i(TAG, "amount of time       : " + testingTime + "s");
                        if (testingTime>=10){
                            speedTestSocket.closeSocketJoinRead();
                        }

                    }
                }
            };

            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 1000);
            speedTestSocket.startUpload("1.testdebit.info", 80, "/", 100000000);

            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Float result) {

            chart.notifyDataSetChanged(); // let the chart know it's data changed
            chart.invalidate(); // refresh
            chart.animateY(1000, Easing.EasingOption.EaseOutBack);
            mRunningBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    }

}
```

EDIT: Added logcat logs

```
04-07 12:18:09.958 26390-26432/? E/dalvikvm: can't open /mnt/sdcard/20160407-101809.hprof: Permission denied
04-07 12:18:09.968 26390-26432/? E/AndroidRuntime: Error reporting crash
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure during heap dump; check log output for details
                                                       at dalvik.system.VMDebug.dumpHprofData(Native Method)
                                                       at dalvik.system.VMDebug.dumpHprofData(VMDebug.java:302)
                                                       at android.os.Debug.dumpHprofData(Debug.java:885)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:89)
                                                       at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
                                                       at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
04-07 12:18:09.978 278-507/? I/WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{418e33c8 com.thtanalyzer.thtanalyzer/com.thtanalyzer.thtanalyzer.MainActivity paused=false}
04-07 12:18:09.978 278-1628/? I/ActivityManager: Process com.thtanalyzer.thtanalyzer (pid 26390) has died.
04-07 12:18:09.978 278-1628/? W/ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{41a7bdd8 com.thtanalyzer.thtanalyzer/.SpeedTestActivity}: app died, no saved state
04-07 12:18:09.988 278-396/? D/NetworkPolicy: mMSimTelephonyManager.getDataSubscription() = 0
```

EDIT2: Added permissions

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Comment: @AnupDasari Thank you for your comment. I added logcat.

Comment: Have you given file permission to your app? Seems like a permission issue is crashing the app.

Comment: @RuchiraRandana I think that I have all permissions I need. I Updated my post with permissions thart application is using. Do I miss one?

Comment: But I'm assuming that your speed-test works by uploading a file to a specific server. I think the problem is that it does not provide the permission to read the file.

Comment: @RuchiraRandana It generates random sets of data and then starts to upload. it is using random function to generate numbers that is filled to buffer. that vuffer uploads on server

Comment: Can you anyway add the following and see whether it works.

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Maybe some other part is using.

I'm suggesting so, because I see the following in your log.

can't open /mnt/sdcard/20160407-101809.hprof: Permission denied

Comment: Added permission for reading/writing to external storage, something is trying to access the SD card, but does not have the permission, the logcat is pretty clear about that.

Answer (score 0):

Define `testButtonClicked Click Listener` Before actually setting it as A listener so the code will be like

```
.............your code .......

private final View.OnClickListener testButtonClicked = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            new SpeedTestTask().execute();
        }
    };
```

**then this line :**

```
findViewById(R.id.start_test).setOnClickListener(testButtonClicked);
```

....................................
..
**your rest of the code again**

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank for oyur answer @LaxmanBhattarai. I tried your code but I got same problem.